How to get PrimaryID value of a data when clicking on a link value in the Datatable
I am using ASP.NET Core 6 MVC C#. I have a table like this:
   <div class="card-body">
        <table class="table display table-bordered" id="DATATABLE"></table>         
   </div>

I have a Student class with StudID (int - PrimaryID), Name (string), Class (int) properties. And the table is shown like this.

In the above pic, the Class value 9 is a hyperlink and 100 is the PrimaryID of that row.
I am looking for a way to get the PrimaryID when clicking on 9.
What I have tried is as shown below.
     $("#DATATABLE").DataTable({
         serverSide: true,
         filter: true,
         searchDelay: 1000,
         scrollY: StaticData.TABLE_HEIGHT + 'px',
         lengthMenu: StaticData.TABLE_PAGE_SIZE,            
         scrollCollapse: true,
         ajax: {
          url: '/STUD_MANAGEMENT/LoadStudents',
          type: 'GET',
          datatype: 'json',
          headers: { 'RequestVerificationToken': 'your json token' },                
          dataSrc: (json) => {
          json = json.data;              
          return json;
         }
         },
         columnDefs: [{ className: "dt-center", targets: [3], width: '2%', }],
         columns: [
         { data: 'STUD_ID', title: 'Stud ID', autoWidth: false, visible : false },
         { data: 'NAME', title: 'Name', autoWidth: true },
         { data: "CLASS", title: 'Class', autoWidth: true,
                 "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
                 if(type === 'display')
                 {
                    data = '<a href="' + data + '" onclick = "clickLink()">' + data + '</a>';
                 }
                     return data;
                }
            }           
        ],
     });


      function clickLink() {
        alert('studid is ??? ');
        }


Given the table provided has the first column as StudID, why are you mapping the data to STUD_ID?

You have to send more information to the render of this column (through data).
Try the code below :
 $("#DATATABLE").DataTable({
     serverSide: true,
     filter: true,
     searchDelay: 1000,
     scrollY: StaticData.TABLE_HEIGHT + 'px',
     lengthMenu: StaticData.TABLE_PAGE_SIZE,            
     scrollCollapse: true,
     ajax: {
      url: '/STUD_MANAGEMENT/LoadStudents',
      type: 'GET',
      datatype: 'json',
      headers: { 'RequestVerificationToken': 'your json token' },                
      dataSrc: (json) => {
      json = json.data;              
      return json;
     }
     },
     columnDefs: [{ className: "dt-center", targets: [3], width: '2%', }],
     columns: [
     { data: 'STUD_ID', title: 'Stud ID', autoWidth: false, visible : false },
     { data: 'NAME', title: 'Name', autoWidth: true },
     { data: null, title: 'Class', autoWidth: true,
             "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
             if(type === 'display')
             {
                data = '<a href="' + data.CLASS + '" onclick = "clickLink('+data.STUD_ID+')">' + data.CLASS + '</a>';
             }
                 return data;
            }
        }           
    ],
 });


  function clickLink(id) {
    alert('studid is '+id);
    }


In the above code, how we can prevent navigation to another page and at the same time, pop up a child window when clicking on the link button ???
